# zref-abspage and perpage incompatibility

Tags: zref

It seems that `zref-abspage` and `perpage` both defines the `abspage` counter so

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{perpage}
\usepackage{zref-abspage}
\begin{document}
This is a test 
\end{document}
```

would produce error.

How should this be fixed? it seems that changing loading order will fix it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, I know it already and have prepared version 3.0 of `zref`. In `zref-abspage` I rename the counter to `zabspage`.  Also I take the opportunity of the major version step to change the way, the counter is increased. Before version 3.0 the counter is increased during shipout time via `\AtBeginShipout`, that means that in the output routine the counter is not yet updated to the value for the page like counter `page`. With version 3.0 the counter `zabspage` shows to the next page number and it is increased after the shipout like the behaviour of counter `page`.

Because I have not finished the work on other parts of the bundle, the next release of my bundle will be later in the year.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Currently both packages wants to use the same counter name, but incrementing it at different times. Thus I can't see, how `savesym` can be of help here.

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but others may bump into this, as bigfoot and manyfoot use perpage.

Apparently, this change has never been incorporated into zref-abspage, nor will it be: https://github.com/ho-tex/zref/issues/3#issuecomment-564498677 .

A possible workaround:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
% First fool perpage into thinking the counter is already defined
\def\c@abspage{INVALID PLACEHOLDER}
\RequirePackage{perpage}
% Now create an alternative counter name...
\AddAbsoluteCounter{pp@abspage}
% And redefine the perpage macro that uses it.
\def\theabspage{\ifx\thepage\relax
    \noexpand\thepp@abspage
  \else
    \number\c@pp@abspage
  \fi}
% Finally, clean up the mess we did.
\undef{\c@abspage}
\makeatother
```